# Get no of rows affected after update and insert in Mybatis3

Tags: spring-mvc, mybatis

I am using mybatis 3 as a persistance framework along with spring mvc.

My query is how to find the no of rows affected after an insert,update of delete using mybatis 3?

Answer (score 5):

Mybatis insert/update/delete Methods will always return an integer. This is the number of affected rows.

See http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/java-api.html#sqlSessions -> Statement execution methods